# Standard error/deviation of the coefficients in OLS

Tags: multiple-regression, standard-deviation, least-squares, standard-error, regression-coefficients

In OLS, the variance of the regression coefficients are computed as
$$
    \mathrm{Var}(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2(\mathbf{X}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{X})^{-1}.
$$

Now, if I need to compute the *standard deviations* of the regression coefficients, it would seem natural to compute them as
$$
    \mathrm{sd}(\hat{\beta}) = \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\beta})},
$$
and the corresponding standard errors as
$$
    \mathrm{se}(\hat{\beta}) = \frac{\mathrm{sd}(\hat{\beta})}{\sqrt{n}}.
$$

However, this is not what you find in any text book on multiple regression. What they say is that
$$
    \mathrm{se}(\hat{\beta}) = \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\beta})}.
$$

But this would make
$$
    \mathrm{sd}(\hat{\beta}) = \mathrm{se}(\hat{\beta})\sqrt{n},
$$
and thus
$$
    \mathrm{sd}(\hat{\beta})^2 \neq \mathrm{Var}(\hat{\beta}).
$$

Does anyone know what I have misunderstood here? Could you please explain?

Comment: The standard error is the standard deviation. You appear to be confusing this situation with the standard error of a sample mean being the standard deviation of the data divided by square root of the sample size.

Comment: Yes, I believe that is my confusion. My goal is to compute the power of a regression coefficient, and I would like to express that $\frac{\sqrt{n}\hat{\beta}_i}{sd(\hat{\beta}_i)} \sim t$. That way I can both compute the power, and the number of observations, $n$, that are required to reach a particular power. Unless I have $se = sd/\sqrt{n}$, I cannot compute the number of required observations, $n$.

Comment: That power calculation (as far as I'm aware) is not simple. It will depend on the correlations among the predictor variables.

Comment: In what I've found, the t-test (of $H_0: \hat{\beta_i}=0$, $H_A: \hat{\beta_i}\neq0$) for a single regression coefficient is $T = \frac{\hat{\beta_i}}{se(\hat{\beta_i})}$, when the hypothesised ($H_0$) value of $\beta_i=0$. Then I thought I'd use the equation A1 and A2 from Dupont and Plummer (1998) (http://www.biostat.washington.edu/~yanez/b578D/materials/dupontplummer.pdf) to compute the power and #obs. Hmm, I just realised that if sd = se in the OLS setting, I should still be able to use those equations.